# NSMutableArray check if object already exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I am not sure how to go about this. I have an **NSMutableArray** (addList) which holds all the items to be added to my datasource NSMutableArray.

I now want to check if the object to be added from the addList array already exists in the datasource array. If it does not exist add the item, if exists ignore.

Both the objects have a string variable called iName which i want to compare.

Here is my code snippet

```
-(void)doneClicked{
    for (Item *item in addList){
        /*
        Here i want to loop through the datasource array 
        */
        for(Item *existingItem in appDelegate.list){
            if([existingItem.iName isEqualToString:item.iName]){
                // Do not add
            }
            else{
                [appDelegate insertItem:item];
            } 
        }
}
```

But i find the item to be added even if it exists.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: It is a logic mistake, see my answer

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I found a solution, may not be the most efficient of all, but atleast works

```
NSMutableArray *add=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (Item *item in addList){
        if ([appDelegate.list containsObject:item])
            {}
        else
            [add addObject:item];
}
```

Then I iterate over the add array and insert items.

Answer (score 76):

There is a very useful method for this in NSArray i.e.   **containsObject**.

```
NSArray *array;
array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Nicola", @"Margherita",                                       @"Luciano", @"Silvia", nil];
if ([array containsObject: @"Nicola"]) // YES
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Use `NSPredicate`.

```
NSArray *list = [[appDelegate.list copy] autorelease];

for (Item *item in addList) {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"iName MATCHES %@", item.iName];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if ([filteredArray count] > 0) [appDelegate insertItem:item];
}
```

Comment: +1 nice answer.  Also avoids the mutating collection exception that would happen if the method used in the question actually worked.

Comment: I tried the above edited solution. First thing, the program crashes without showing any error. Secondly, the Item is added even if it exists in the datasource list

Comment: @simon: thanks for the answer. But still the program crashes :( 
I am just banging my head now :(

Comment: @Narayanan, Can you tell in which line the program crashes?

Comment: @simon: It crashes where we create the predicate. 

**[NSComparisonPredicate isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7154070**

Comment: @Narayanan, Remove the single quotes `'` from the predicate format and check. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @simon: I am sorry. The program crashes. :( :(

Comment: @Narayanan, Alright. Check if the objects in the *addList* are getting release somewhere or you have some other problem.

Comment: No. They are not released anywhere else

Comment: @simon: I am not able to figure it out :(

Comment: @Narayanan, Try to print the `iNames` in the `addList` and `appDelegate.list` and check if they are valid.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try [`indexOfObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:)?

```
-(void)doneClicked{
    for (Item *item in addList){
        if([appDelegate.list indexOfObject:item] == NSNotFound){
            [appDelegate insertItem:item];
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:** You have a logical mistake, not mistake in code. assume the first array is ['a', 'b', 'c'], and the second is ['a', 'x', 'y', 'z']. When you iterate with 'a' through the second array it won't add 'a' to second array in the first iteration (compare 'a' with 'a') but will add during the second (compare 'a' with 'x'). That is why you should implement [`isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) method (see below) in your 'Item' object and use the code above.

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject {
    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[Item class]])
        return ([self.iName isEqualToString:((Item *)anObject).iName]);
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: @NR4TR: i want to compare the names alone. Not the entire object

Comment: Yes i get it now. But when i use the code you have updated, I get the following error 

[Item isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x712ee70

Comment: Check your `isEqual:` method implementation inside your `Item` class

Comment: sorry, I do not seem to follow. Item is a class that i created myself and I do not have an isEqual method at all. 

Can you please help me in detail ?

Comment: see updates. just paste this `isEqual:` method to your `Item` implementation

Comment: I still get the same error. 

**[Item isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x712ee70**

Comment: please read docs carefully and try to do some debugging yourself, it's really hard to do debugging via comments

Comment: I will try debugging :( I thought this should be simple

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at NSSet. You can add objects and the object will only be added if the object is unique. You can create a NSSet from an NSArray or vise versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `isEquals` and `hash` on the object so that it returns a YES / NO based on the comparison of the iName property.

Once you have that you can use...

```
- (void)removeObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)otherArray
```

To clean the list before adding all the remaining objects.

Comment: First, I want to compare the names alone and not the entire object.

Comment: Consider reading documentation about `isEquals` method, it could help

Comment: Yes, the idea of overriding the isEquals is that you can then define what you consider 'equal'. Normally the runtime will look at two objects and if they are not the same instance will return false. By overriding the isEquals method you can say 'actually I don't care if the OBJECTS are not the same, in my eyes, these two items are the same if the name matches.'

Answer (score 2):

NR4TR said correctly but i think one **break** statement is sufficient

```
if([existingItem.iName isEqualToString:item.iName]){
                // Do not add
break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert Lowercase and Trim whitespace and then check..

```
[string lowercaseString];
```

and

```
NSString *trim = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You compare the addList's first object and appDelegate.list's first object, if they are not equal, you insert the addList's object. The logic is wrong, you should compare one addList's object with every appDelegate.list's object.