# iOS Check the String contains in Table View row or not?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

In my code I have an `NSMutableArray`. I want to get all values from that array into `String` and I want to check the string values are in another array named **hairStyleManIDArray** that was load in `tableview` if the string value in that **tableview(hairStyleManIDArray)** array means i want to assign checkmark for the particular row else remove the checkmark.

The tableview loaded array look like this,

```
hairStyleManIDArray is : (
23,
32
```

)

The Mutable array look like this,

```
idMutableArray is  (
     30,
     29,
     32,
     41
     )
```

So I used the following method to convert NSMutableArray to String.

```
idStr = idMutableArray.componentsJoined(by: ",") as String
    print("idStr is ",idStr)
```

Now the String look like this,

```
idStr is : 30,29,32,41
```

Now I using this method to check the string value is in table view row or not.

```
if hairStyleManIDArray[indexPath.row] as! String == idStr {
                    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.accessoryType = .none
                }
```

To check in both array value 32 was found in both so i want to set checkmark in particular row but it is not working please help me for compplete the task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this SO Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291412/nsmutablearray-check-if-object-already-exists

Comment: your **hairStyleManIDArray.count** and **idMutableArray.count** both are equal or   not

Comment: That is not same as this bro and that is objective-c this is swift so please don't make as a duplicate bro, I am new for coding.@andrewbuilder

Comment: at present no one closed your question

Comment: Not equal bro, hairStyleManIDArray values are from server and I am added values to idMutableArray at run time bro..@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: then use nirav answer use the `contains` keyboard for match the dynamic keys

Comment: When I check single value it works bro but multi values means not working.@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @saravanaKumarB Don't compare string with array of string instead of that you need to simply use contains with your array to check it contains object or not

Comment: I will check and try this code bro.@NiravD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert `idMutableArray` to String instead of that simply use `contains` to check object is inside or not also instead of `NS(Mutable)Array` in swift use swift type array means `[String]`.

```
if idMutableArray.contains(hairStyleManIDArray[indexPath.row] as? String ?? "") {
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Comment: I will check and try now bro.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for the suggestion but I preferred to use else block here because that gave you easy understanding.

Comment: what the use of else block, ok we provide the optimze the answer,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Bro I think everyone have different coding style don't you think so

Comment: Thanks bro very helpful for me@Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following without converting the values to String.

```
let hairStyleID = hairStyleManIDArray[indexPath.row]
if idMutableArray.contains(hairStyleID)
{
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro for the guidance.